# tkinter puts second frame with toplevel

Tags: python, tkinter, toplevel

I'm programing a background to this program and it gives a second frame when I run it. I dont know why this happens but it does. here is the program

```
import tkinter as tk
import os
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
parent = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
assets = os.path.join(parent,"assets")
backgrounds = os.path.join(assets,"backgrounds")
print(assets)
root = tk.Toplevel()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()
path = os.path.join(backgrounds,"red to blue.png")
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
panel = tk.Label(root, image=img)
panel.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why are you creating a `Toplevel()` without a `Tk()`? Change `root = tk.Toplevel()` to `root = tk.Tk()`

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the answer was that I needed it to be `tk.Tk()` instead of `tk.Toplevel()` and it works now.